# How to decrease cart items quantity by one

Tags: node.js, express

I have been trying to create a shopping cart where I can decrease  the number of quantity in cart items but I don't know how to do it and also how to do the testing it with postman. This is what have implemented so far. I need to decrease the quantity for example if user change there mind from 3 items to 2 items I want to decrease the number by one and also change the price and total to the current quantity

```
let { productId } = req.body;
const quantity = Number.parseInt(req.body.quantity);

let productObject = await Products.findOne({ _id: productId });
let cartObject = await CartItem.findOne({ status: 1 });
let productPriceObject = await Price.findOne({ productId: productObject._id, status: 1 });

if (cartObject.items.unitCount <= quantity) {
    var oldQuantity = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < cartObject.items.length; i++) {
        if (cartObject.items[i]._id == productId) {
            oldQuantity = cartObject.items[i].unitCount;
        }
    }

    let cartUpdateObject = await CartItem.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: cartObject._id,
        productId: items.productId,
        status: 1,
        guestId: req.guest._id,
    }, { $set: { "items.$.unitCount": quantity } }, { new: true });

    if (!!cartUpdateObject) {

        cartObject.items[i].total = cartObject.items[i].unitCount * productPriceObject.value;
        cartObject.items[i].price = productPriceObject.value;
        cartObject.subTotal = cartObject.items.map((item) => item.total).reduce((acc, next) => acc + next);

    } else {
        return res.status(400)
            .json({
                success: false,
                message: "unable to update quantity",
                error,
            });
    }
}
```

This is my schema model for cart model I used to create the cart items

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ItemSchema = new Schema({
    productId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product",
    },
    unitCount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: [1, 'Quantity can not be less then 1.']
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);

const CartSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },

    items: [ItemSchema],

    subTotal: {
        default: 0,
        type: Number
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('cart', CartSchema);
```

Comment: I don't think it is a wise design to make an api call every increase or decrease in item number,item quantity and price should be handle on the frontend then you can make api call to see if requested item is available and then you proceed to payment method.

Comment: You mean I don't need to include decrease of item in my api call for cart items right

Comment: yes that should be done inside your frontend